# Device not detect the online/ offline status

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my phonegap application i want to check the device online/offline status.

```
Cordova version is 3.3
Android version 4.2.2
Jquery Mobile 1.3
```

So i use the following methods to detect online/offline.
Method 1:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady(){   
    connectionStatusOnline = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    alert(connectionStatusOnline);
}
```

it always return **offline**.

Method 2:

```
document.addEventListener("online", toggleon, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", toggleoff, false);
function toggleon() {
    alert("online");

}
function toggleoff() {
    alert("offline");

}
```

in **method 2 it never calls toogleon or toogleoff**.

Method 3:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
//document.addEventListener("offline", toggleCon, false);
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

in method 3 it shows **Connection undefined**

I have all the plugins in `config.xml and set all the permission in manifest`.

Comment: Can you tell me your project structure(mean www folder structure).

Comment: @Arut html files are in www/html folder and js files are www/js and css files www/css

Comment: ok where is cordova.js and cordova_pluins.js files..

Comment: @Arut inside my www/js files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your cordova.js and cordova_plugin.js files are inside www/js folder.`So the file API's are called in this staratergy`. SO the device is not detect the device is offline/online. I faced similar issue before. What i did copy the cordova.js and cordova_pluins.js files into **www** **folder**.

Your `project directory should be like www/cordova.js and www/cordova_plugins.js`

Not `www/js/cordova.js and www/js/cordova_plugin.js`

Answer (score 0):

Add network plugin through CLI ... [Link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection)

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

Then

```
<script>

   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady()
    {

        if(navigator.connection.type==0)
        {
              toggleoff();  
        }
        else if(navigator.connection.type=='none')
        {
              toggleoff();  
        }
        else
        {
              toggleon();
        }

     }
</script>
```